# How to start elastic search using command terminal in ubuntu

Tags: elasticsearch, command-line, installation, ubuntu-14.04

While installing elastic search in ubuntu-16.04, my process wasn't completed even after several minutes.  I have written 'bin/elasticsearch' as my last command in the terminal suring installation. What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: `bin/elasticsearch` is not for installing ES but for launching it. So it's normal that this command is not returning, it just means your ES server is up and running (which is a good thing)

Answer (score 17):

For installing Elasticsearch you just need to download and decompress the file.

Then go to you Elasticsearch folder and type

```
./bin/elasticsearch
```

The server will start, but if you exit the terminal or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> it will stop.

You can add `-d` if you want to run it as a deamon in the background.

To see if Elasticsearch is running, just type

```
curl 'http://localhost:9200/?pretty'
```

or

```
ps aux | grep elastic
```

To stop the service, just kill the process.

Answer (score 1):

install the `.tar` file from the website. Extract it. Go to its bin folder and do a "`./elasticsearch`". It'll be up and running on `port 9200`

Answer (score 1):

One way to start Elasticsearch is by extracting the `.tar` file and entering the *bin* directory and running the command `./elasticsearch`.

The other way, if you install it using `apt` or `apt-get` is by running `systemctl start elasticsearch` or `systemctl start elasticsearch.service`.

If you need root privileges, you can prepend `sudo` with the command.